# How can I import a dataset from Excel using col_types (function read_xlsx) just for some variables in R?

Tags: r, date, import, import-from-excel

I'd like to import a dataset from Excel. I need to import the variables which contains the word "DATE" as `col_types = "date"`. If I set `col_types = "date"` for all the data, the variables which aren't dates are filled with `NA`. I'd like to set a condition on that option (`col_types`). I used the next code:

```
base <- read_xlsx("C:/Users/.../base.xlsx", col_types = "date")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to first read the whole spreadsheet and hence to select the wanted columns:

```
library(tidyverse)
read_xlsx("C:/Users/.../base.xlsx", col_types = "date") %>%
  select(contains("DATE"))
```

Comment: It is not exactly what I would like to do, but it's really helpful! Thanks.